# OpenSuse : Not able to login after having disabled Wayland

Tags: opensuse, gnome, xorg

Because of common issues with a laggy mouse, I decided to disable Wayland on my brand new installation of OpenSuse on my Desktop PC.

I had performance issues with Wayland, but when I selected "Gnome with Xorg" at login - everything worked fine later.

So I completely disabled Wayland by appending this line to the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Since I don't have any lags on the login screen - no more "Gnome with Xorg" choice on the login settings.

But when I input my password and submit, I get a prompt black screen for a second, and then I get back to the login screen.

Do you know where I can gather logs for this issue and how I can fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The first place I would look for is: the .xsession-errors files in your login home folder.

```
cat .xsession-errors
cat .xsession-errors | more (large file)
```

It's the error log produced by your X windows system